# using QBO v3 - search for invoices that have changed in the last month

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How can I get a list of all of the invoices that have changed in a date frame. I am writing a program to go out and get the modified invoices but can't do it so I have to read through them all.

I'm using IPP .Net

Here's what I've done so far:

```
DataService dataService = new DataService(serviceContext);
QueryService<Invoice> invoiceQueryService = new QueryService<Invoice>(serviceContext);

IEnumerable<Invoice> InvoiceList = invoiceQueryService.OrderBy(c => c.Id);
```

What I'd like to do is add something like   .Where(c => c.MetaData.LastChangedDB > '1/1/2014')

but when I try that I get an exception that the expression is not valid.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA - Jeff.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Change Data Capture` functionality for this:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00600_changedata_operation

Those APIs are specifically meant for exactly the situation that you're running into - fetching data changed in a given date range.

The API endpoint you need to hit is going to look something like this:

`https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1234/cdc?entities=Invoice&changedSince=2012-07-20T22:25:51-07:00`

Note that you can specify the entity (or entities - comma separated list) to fetch changed records of, and a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in C# for CDC operation:

```
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity>  entityList = new List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity>();
                        entityList.Add(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice());
                        var DataService = new DataService(context);            
                        var CDCResponse = DataService.CDC(entityList, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).entities;
```

Or try the following queries:

```
QueryService<Invoice> QueryService = new QueryService<Invoice>(context);
 List<Invoice> accs = QueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * FROM Account  WHERE     MetaData.LastUpdatedTime >= '2000-01-01T00:00:00'").ToList();
List<Invoice> accs1 = QueryService.Where(c =>c.MetaData.LastUpdatedTime <= new DateTime(2012, 06, 30, 11, 20, 50)).ToList();
```